# Dynamic jasper report header image

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am creating dynamic jasper reports. Things are looking fine. How do I add a dynamic header image to the generated reports?

I am using

```
FastReportBuilder fr = new FastReportBuilder();
Style headerStyle = new Style();
headerStyle.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
headerStyle.setPadding(5);

fr.setTitle("Title")
    .setSubtitle("Sub title")
    .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)
    .setUseFullPageWidth(true)
    .setPageSizeAndOrientation(Page.Page_A4_Landscape())
    .setTitleHeight(100)
    .setTitleStyle(headerStyle);
```

But its not working.
Reports will be exported in pdf, csv, and html formats.

Comment: May be this article help you: http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/inserting-images-from-database-into-jasper-reports/

Comment: No its not helpful for me. I am looking into FastReportBuilder.addImageBanner(). what do you think.

Comment: I think you are right. The sample: http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/WhenNoDataTest.html

Comment: Its not showing image. <img src="nullimg_0_0_2"> :(

Comment: Why the file name without extension? Is the image path is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me

```
fr.setUseFullPageWidth(true)
        .setPageSizeAndOrientation(Page.Page_A4_Landscape())
        .addFirstPageImageBanner("path/logo_strip.jpg", 800, 50, ImageBanner.ALIGN_LEFT);
```